# como utilizar arraylist para fijar valores desde otra clase

Tags: java

Tengo un programa que he ido modificando pasa a paso para conseguir fijar datos en un arraylist desde otra clase. Algo similar a como se hace con los métodos get y set para atributos. Sin embargo no logro fijar la información en este arraylist. ¿Alguien me puede ayudar?

Producto.java

```
import java.util.*;
public class Producto {
    private String categoria;
    private String categoriaMarca;
    ArrayList<String> categoriaProductos = new ArrayList<String>();
    public Producto(String categoria, String categoriaMarca) {
        this.categoria = categoria;
        this.categoriaMarca = categoriaMarca;
    }
    public String getCategoria() {
        return categoria;
    }
    public String getCategoriaMarca() {
        return categoriaMarca;
    }
    public String toString() {
        return "Categoria: "+this.getCategoria() + " /  Marca: " + this.getCategoriaMarca();
    }
    public void categoriaProductos() {
        categoriaProductos.add("Categoria: "+this.getCategoria() + " /  Marca: " + this.getCategoriaMarca());
    } 
}
```

Aplicación.java

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.*;
public class Aplicacion {
    public void catalogo() {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        ArrayList<Producto> cProductos = new ArrayList<Producto>();
        ArrayList<Producto> catalogo = new ArrayList<Producto>();
        String categoria, producto, resp1;
        for(int i=0; i<2; i++) {
            System.out.println("Escriba la categoría del producto: ");
            categoria = scan.nextLine();
            System.out.println("Ingrese el producto: ");
            producto = scan.nextLine();
            catalogo.add(new Producto(categoria, producto)); 
        }
    }
    public void cProductos() {
        Scanner sca = new Scanner(System.in);
        ArrayList<Producto> cProductos = new ArrayList<Producto>();
        String resp1;
        System.out.println("Para ver el catálogo de productos, presione C ");
        resp1 = sca.nextLine(); 
        do {
            for (int f = 0; f < cProductos.size(); f++) {
                System.out.println(cProductos.get(f));
            }
        } while (resp1 == "C") ;
    }
    public static void main(String[] arg) {
        Aplicacion app1;
        app1 = new Aplicacion();
        app1.catalogo();
        app1.cProductos();
    }
}
```

Comment: no es que no logras guardar informacion.. la guardas, pero como el arraylist es local a la funcion, se pierde al salir de ella...

Comment: Hola, dices que quieres fijar los datos en un `ArrayList`, pero, ¿Qué datos? ¿En qué `ArrayList`? ¿Es en el de tu clase `Producto`? ¿Es en alguno de los de tu clase `Aplicacion`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hola te lo debería de decir como comentario pero el problema básicamente es la definición de como quieres que las cosas funcionen. Te recomiendo echar a un ojo al patrón de diseño orientado a objetos y que puedas separar las funcionalidades para que a la hora de programar el código te sea mas facil y limpio de realizar.

La solucion de lo que necesitas es la siguiente:
Clase Producto:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Producto {
    private String categoria;
    private String categoriaMarca;

    ArrayList<String> categoriaProductos = new ArrayList<String>();

    public Producto(String categoria, String categoriaMarca) {
        this.categoria = categoria;
        this.categoriaMarca = categoriaMarca;
    }
    public String getCategoria() {
        return categoria;
    }
    public String getCategoriaMarca() {
        return categoriaMarca;
    }

    public void setCategoria(String categoria) {
        this.categoria = categoria;
    }

    public void setCategoriaMarca(String categoriaMarca) {
        this.categoriaMarca = categoriaMarca;
    }

    public ArrayList<String> getCategoriaProductos() {
        return categoriaProductos;
    }

    public String toString() {
        return "Categoria: "+this.getCategoria() + " /  Marca: " + this.getCategoriaMarca();
    }
    public void categoriaProductos() {
        categoriaProductos.add("Categoria: "+this.getCategoria() + " /  Marca: " + this.getCategoriaMarca());
    }
```

Clase Aplicacion:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {
    ArrayList<Producto> catalogo = new ArrayList<Producto>();

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Main app1 = new Main();
        app1.catalogo();
        app1.cProductos();
    }

    public void catalogo() {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        //ArrayList<Producto> cProductos = new ArrayList<Producto>();

        String categoria, producto/*, resp1*/;

        for(int i=0; i<2; i++) {
            System.out.println("Escriba la categoría del producto: ");
            categoria = scan.nextLine();
            System.out.println("Ingrese el producto: ");
            producto = scan.nextLine();
            //catalogo.add(new Producto(categoria, producto));
            if (catalogo.isEmpty()){
                catalogo.add(new Producto(categoria,producto));
                catalogo.get(0).categoriaProductos();
            }else{
                catalogo.get(0).setCategoria(categoria);
                catalogo.get(0).setCategoriaMarca(producto);
                catalogo.get(0).categoriaProductos();
            }

        }
    }
    public void cProductos() {
        Scanner sca = new Scanner(System.in);
        //ArrayList<Producto> cProductos = new ArrayList<Producto>();
        String resp1;
        System.out.println("Para ver el catálogo de productos, presione C ");
        resp1 = sca.nextLine();

        do {
            for (int f = 0; f < catalogo.size(); f++) {
                //System.out.println(catalogo.get(f));//esto solo retorna lo ultimo que guardaste

                for (int p = 0; p<catalogo.get(f).getCategoriaProductos().size(); p++) {
                    System.out.println(catalogo.get(f).getCategoriaProductos().get(p));
                }

            }
            //Esto es para ponerle fin al ciclo de lo contrario quedaria infinito
            System.out.println("Para ver el catálogo de productos, presione C ");
            resp1 = sca.nextLine();
        } while (resp1.equals("C"));//texto en java se compara con equals
    }
}
```

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu ayuda